# Save picture with XML file in dropbox

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, dropbox

I am working on project, in that i required to send photos to the dropbox with attach XML file, problem is that How can i send it with individual photos for particular xml file in core data, I tried to work with making zip file of both and then exporting it to dropbox and then importing and parsing same xml via dropbox, but its not working so Is there any solution for it?

Please Guide me
Thank you

Comment: "It's not working" how? It's not at all clear what kind of problem you're having, or what you have tried to do so far.

Comment: I want to do is : I am sending photos also with xml , and photo is only for particular XML, so How can I managed that

Comment: You still haven't said what you tried and how it's not working. What kind of problem are you seeing that you want to fix? "It's not working" is a completely useless statement on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send the xml file to dropbox, have the xml file contain a reference to the image and also upload the image.

And you are done!